# Is String Theory compatible with Presentism?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics

Maybe if it was formulated using Neo-Lorentzian interpretation of Special relativity instead of Minkowski spacetime? I don't know

Thank you for answer!

Comment: Is there a Lorentzian interpretation of quantum field theory, at least? I do not know but it sounds like a question for Physics SE. [Tumulka](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0607124.pdf) discusses some generalizations of Bohmian mechanics to QFT that involve a time foliation, so perhaps a presentist can latch on to that. It is already highly technical and extension to string theory will be yet more technical. Here really is not the right place for this question, the philosophical part is a side issue.

Answer (score 1):

String theory as developed so far preserves the [relativity of simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity) of other quantum field theories, meaning you can define different local inertial frames with different definitions of simultaneity and the laws of physics will obey the same equations in each of them, so in that sense no particular definition of simultaneity is "preferred" relative to the fundamental laws of physics. And presentism does require a single unique truth about simultaneity to define a shared objective present. You are still free to imagine there is a sort of "metaphysically preferred frame" whose definition of simultaneity is "true" while the others are "false" in a metaphysical sense, as long as one accepts that no possible physical experiment could allow us to empirically determine which definition of simultaneity is the metaphysically preferred one. This idea is discussed for example in the book *An Introduction to the Philosophy of Time* by Sam Baron and Kristie Miller, although on p. 107-108 they do point to some potential philosophical objections to the notion of a metaphysically preferred frame that has no measurable physical consequences whatsoever:

> The idea that some simultaneity class is metaphysically, and not physically, privileged gives rise to two difficulties. First, it may not be in the best interests of the dynamic theory of time to cleave metaphysical from physical privilege. As we saw in Chapter 3, passage theorists hold that we have experiences as of time passing, and that we have those experiences because time does in fact pass. Temporal passage just is the movement of a privileged present. So it would stand to reason that if we experience time’s passing, it must be because we have some experiential connection to the privileged present.
>
> But if the very thing that makes the present privileged is not physical, then it is quite difficult to see how the passage of time could be being experienced. In short, the idea that the present is metaphysically privileged would render the dynamic theory of time susceptible to the makes no difference argument discussed in section 3.7.
>
> Second, it is troubling that the metaphysically privileged simultaneity class is not physically discoverable, at least when that simultaneity class is being used to delimit the present. On such a view it would seem that nature is ‘conspiring’ to keep the privileged present hidden from us. This leads to a sceptical conclusion about the present: for all we know, nothing that is simultaneous with us is present. We may not be in the privileged simultaneity class and thus may not have the privileged perspective on the universe needed to be present. On some dynamic theories of time, this has alarming implications. Presentists maintain that only present entities exist. For the presentist, then, we have no way of knowing whether the things we take to be simultaneous with us even exist!

Comment: I do not think that undetectable in principle metaphysics is that concerning to many people. Theology, moral realism and qualia show that they are happy to accept realities beyond scientific detection, or even beyond any human detection. And if qualia are scientifically invisible why shouldn't "true" time passage be as well. Physical and "experiential" time are commonly contrasted. What I find more interesting is whether it is mathematically possible to coherently formulate a string theory with aether background and some dynamical mechanism a la Lorentz that "conspires" to hide it.

Comment: @Conifold With qualia though, advocates would say they are at least subjectively "detectable", but in the view above true simultaneity for distant events (on Earth and Mars, say) couldn't be determined even in a first-person subjective sense. And believers in qualia as a metaphysically distinct reality seem to often resist the idea that they are causally inert (epiphenomalism) even if they do accept that physical events can be explained by physical causes, for ex. Chalmers starting on p. 150 of "The Conscious Mind" suggests strategies to avoid epiphenomalism, like "causal overdetermination".

Answer (score 0):

I would say **yes.**

Presentism argues that only things in the present exist.
That doesn't mean you throw out the concept of time in-and-of itself.

We need time to function day to day; presentism is a **philosophical position** on what we call **time**, which is a word we use when referring to the fact that everything **appears** to be changing in a linear, unidirectional, constant process.

For example; one cannot use presentism to excuse the fact that one was an hour late to work today. However you choose to view the process philosophically does not change its observable properties.

Going from this assumption (that presentism tells us nothing of the **observable** properties of time), it seems reasonable to me that any theory drawn from said observable properties is compatible with presentism.

Presentism concerns itself with the bits of time we can't see.
Physics concerns itself with the bits we can.

Comment: A theory, string theory in particular, is a lot more than any collection of observations. Theories make global claims that are untestable in principle, just like presentism. Whether string theory is compatible with presentism depends on whether a preferred frame can be introduced into it. That is a mathematical question that cannot be answered based on either observations or philosophical generalities.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I'll admit I'm no physicist.
Would it be reasonable to assert then, that if string theory were ever **proven true**, my argument would be valid, but it isn't in its current state?

Comment: @Conifold - a "preferred frame" as physicists normally define it is not a purely mathematical issue, it must have testable consequences. Though as I said in my answer you can have a metaphysically preferred frame which is different than how physicists would use the term, which could perhaps be part of a mathematical "interpretation" of a theory similar to the different interpretations of quantum mechanics that don't make any distinct empirical predictions.

Comment: Theories are never proven "true". Classical mechanics was true enough observationally, but it asserted things about space, time, determinism, etc. way beyond that. Similarly, string theory will assert things way beyond its observational basis. While presentism may be compatible with the latter it will not make it automatically compatible with the theory, no matter how "true".